# Run my own full node for prevent front running

Tags: full-node, frontrunning

If I run my own full node and I use to send all my transactions to Etherum do I prevent my transactions from being front runned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I were in your situation a few months back. The easier and more efficient option would be to seek a dark pool to keep your transaction safe from the public mempool. If your transactions are not visible in the public mempool, they will be safe from front runners.

I suggest you look into Flashbots API. It provides exactly the kind of protection you're looking for: https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-auction/searchers/quick-start/